# Texdoctk unable to find pdf files

Tags: texdoc

I have just installed texlive-latex-extra on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have found that there is a new icon among my applications, which says texdoctk. I opened it but it cannot find any of the files available.
Where should all those document be and how to install them?

Comment: Did you install any doc package (texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra-doc etc.) ?

Comment: I did not install any of these as I thought documentation would come automatically with normal latex installation.

Comment: the documentation is very large so you have to choose the one you really need

Comment: Documentation is only automatically included in the upstream texlive. In the Ubuntu release everything is split up into smaller pieces (a joy to some, annoyance to others). You might want to install the texlive-all pseudo Ubuntu package